# how to convert the binarydata of img to img tags

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

all
I got the binary data of the image(use xhr),let's name this binary data as data
I wonder how to convert data to a real img tags
At first:
I try using *FileReder* to *readAsBinaryString*,but It won't work cause **reader.onloadend** won't fire

Are there other ways to get this done?
Thanks in advance~

```
 $.ajax({
                url:src,
                type:"GET",
                success:function(data){  
    var reader=new FileReader()
    reader.onload=function(e){

        var data=e.target.result
        console.log(data)

   } 
  reader.readAsDataURL(data)
```

...

Comment: Please try `reader.onload` (works fine for me).

Comment: Convert it to Base64 then attach it to the img src directly - data:image/jpg;base64,DATA

Comment: @ComFreek,I've tried,still the same

Comment: @JohnStrickler,I type part of my code ,Is that what you think about?

Comment: @Lanston see my answer below, I've hit the highlights and left some homework.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call `readAsDataURL` and use the `load` event instead.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: I've tried at the very first beginning,the problem is that,the *reader.onload* didn't fire

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encode your binary data.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) on how to base64 binary data in JavaScript.

Then insert the base64 string directly into your image tag.  For example, if the binary data is a JPG image, you could do this (in theory):

```
$.ajax({
  url:src,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(binaryData) {  

    //toBase64 is a made up function, see above
    var base64Data = toBase64(binaryData);

    //assuming img is defined outside of here (not in the scope of this question)
    img.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64Data;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi,I try this ,but I get the same "base64" and this "base64" is strange ,different from the right base64