# img src attribute return as binary data from $.post request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, image

I'm trying to render an image in an html page by making a post request to a php script, which opens the image in a binary mode and then returns the image with the correct content headers and renders it in the img tag. I see the binary data in the console but I'm not sure how to use this to render the image in the html page.

The img src attribute is referencing this url: http://[IP]:[PORT]/img/123. When the request arrives at the server the url is rewritten to point to tracker.php. Within tracker.php a get request is made, which on success, returns an image url and makes another post request with this url as the data. Within the same tracker.php page a php script opens the file referenced by the url in a binary mode and outputs it with the correct headers.

How do I get this data back to the html page img tag and render it correctly? Is this even possible?

Thanks, J

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
#phpinfo();
#var_dump($_REQUEST);
if(isset($_POST['val'])) {

  // open the file in a binary mode
  $name = $_POST['val'];
  $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

  // send the right headers
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

  // dump the picture and stop the script
  fpassthru($fp);
  exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/steal/steal.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jquery/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
steal('jquery/dom/fixture').then(function(){

$.fixture("GET /event/{code}", function(original, settings, headers){
    return [200, "success", { "img_url":"http://path/to/my/img.png" }, {} ]
})

var strObj = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST); ?>;
var str = strObj.q;
var eventCode = str.split('/')[1];

$.ajax({
  url: "/event/"+eventCode,
  success: function(data) {
     var imgUrl = data.img_url;
     $.post('/tracker.php', 'val='+imgUrl, function (response) {
        return response; // push img data from php back to html page img tag.
     });
   }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212802/how-to-convert-the-binarydata-of-img-to-img-tags

Comment: Seems like you are over complicating the issue. The post request returns text only, so does not handle binary. You can base64 encode it, but seems like you could just ask for the image using an image tag, for example like `<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images?image_id=pic.png" />`

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that the image will be used for tracking opened emails, so this request is actually coming from an html email template. The requirement is to not have an image reference in the src attribute. Instead the url http://[IP]:[PORT]/img/123 is captured in a rewrite rule and redirected to the tracker.php script. From here the $_REQUEST data will be used to make a GET request, which on success will return an image url. I need to render this image in the email template from where the src attribute request was made e.g., http://[IP]:[PORT]/img/123.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax post request to php $\_POST vars empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716542/ajax-post-request-to-php-post-vars-empty)